# css scalable menu with last item at bottom

Tags: css, menu, menuitem, scalability

I have a menu list that has a bigger distance between the last item and the item before the last. What I want to accomplish is that on scaling of the parent div's height, the distance should vanish but I also want to decrease the icons when the distance is 0 (should always be a margin-top between the items), but right now I am stuck on scaling where the last item overlaps the items before.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- 
awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
 <div class="scale">
<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-at"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is so far what I got
codepen: [css scalable menu](https://codepen.io/RandomStuffIn2017/pen/yENBYo)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "decrease the icons"?

Comment: You could give the scale div a "min-height"?

Comment: By decreasing the icons I mean I want them to shrink as I'm resizing.